# What is the default wait time for driver.findelement/findelements mthod

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I mean if the element is not present in the page after what time interval it throws exception . FYI this i am not using any wait (implecit/Explicit wait).

Answer (score 3):

It just waits for DOM is ready and checks for element presence. So the interval between DOM readiness and possible `NoSuchElementExcepption` is zero.